# Slide down box menu stops working when I put in a slide show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to web design and really need some help for a class project.  I have a sliding navigation that I'm using with the following Javascript from  http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/07/16/slide-down-box-menu/

```
<!-- The JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            /**
            * for each menu element, on mouseenter, 
            * we enlarge the image, and show both sdt_active span and 
            * sdt_wrap span. If the element has a sub menu (sdt_box),
            * then we slide it - if the element is the last one in the menu
            * we slide it to the left, otherwise to the right
            */
            $('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
                var $elem = $(this);
                $elem.find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                        'width':'170px',
                        'height':'170px',
                        'left':'0px'
                     },400,'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'top':'140px'},500,'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'height':'170px'},300,function(){
                    var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                    if($sub_menu.length){
                        var left = '170px';
                        if($elem.parent().children().length == $elem.index()+1)
                            left = '-170px';
                        $sub_menu.show().animate({'left':left},200);
                    }   
                });
            }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                var $elem = $(this);
                var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                if($sub_menu.length)
                    $sub_menu.hide().css('left','0px');

                $elem.find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'height':'0px'},300)
                     .andSelf().find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                        'width':'0px',
                        'height':'0px',
                        'left':'85px'},400)
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'top':'25px'},500);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When I try to put a slideshow on the page, the navigation stops working.  I've tried several slideshows there is some type of conflict with all of them.  The one I'm trying to use is from http://www.jacklmoore.com/monte.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling animate and stop multiple times all-at-once. Two ways you can deal with this are either building a queue system ([jQuery does have one](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)), or use the callbacks provided (a function that is run after a function does it's job).

To be clear, code like this is all run at once:

```
a.animate1()
b.animate2() //animate2 doesn't wait for animate 1, thus, use of callbacks and/or queues.
```

As a side note, see if you can reduce the parts of code you've used a lot of cut+paste in through use of functions. Good luck on the project!